# how can I change the attr "nofollow" of Links

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

In my spider(inherit from CrawlSpider), I chang the the parameter  "follow" of Rule, but the output Links of LinkExtractor  don' change.like this:

```
    rules = [
        Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(
            allow=[],
            deny=[]),
            follow=True,
        )
    ]
```

the CustomLinkExtractor is my custom LinkExtractor

print Links:

```
[Link(url='www.example.com', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

now I change the rule:

```
 rules = [
            Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(
                allow=[],
                deny=[]),
            )
        ]
```

print Links:

```
[Link(url='www.example.com', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

no change!, so I want to know how to change the parameter "nofollow" , I think the parameter "nofollow" decide whether follow the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Rule's `follow` parameter with LinkExtractor's `nofollow` one.

Some websites use `rel=nofollow` to indicate that web crawlers shouldn't follow this url and that's exactly what linkextractor shows in this case - wether the link node has `rel=nofollow`. It has nothing to do with the `Rule` object.

See [wikipedia's article on `nofollow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow):

> nofollow is a value that can be assigned to the rel attribute of an HTML a element to instruct some search engines that the hyperlink should not influence the ranking of the link's target in the search engine's index.

Comment: Thank you, that help me a lot

Comment: @Zioyi no problem, it is such a confusing naming coincidence!